# SSIS Adding Text Qualifier to Imported Data

Tags: ssis, quickbooks, cdata-drivers

I am trying a CData Driver to import reports from Quickbooks Desktop and export them out as a flat file. The fields are

GL_ID, Debit, Credit

However, when SSIS loads this file, the fields are not currently using text Qualifiers(GL_ID= Hello, World vs GL_ID = "Hello, World"), which means when I import using comma delimiters, any fields which already have commas in them split apart.

How Can I add this missing text qualifier so that fields which have commas in their text are not split up when using a CSV delimiter.

**Highlighted Ex: Row with .... ,LLC loads as 4 Columns instead of 3**

[image]
[image: Loads as 4 Columns instead of 3 Because of ,LLC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the Flat File Connection Manager (not pictured) that is being used by the Flat File Destination.

In the Flat File Connection Manager, on the General tab, you can specify the Text Delimiter (default is None).